# Installshield LE doesn't overwrite files

Tags: visual-studio, installshield, overwrite

Is there a way to prevent Installshield LE (Visual Studio project) from overwriting particular files during installation? or a way is can check if file exists. It would be of great help knowing how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both question is yes.

Installshield keeps track of components and each file that it installs should belong to some component. Each component has a key file and installshield will not try to overwrite files in a component, where the key file has not changed. I believe [this resource](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/FAQFilesOverwrite.htm) may be of some help.

The second option is: you can write any custom action and make installshield call it, thus you can write some simple function to check if a file exists. The starting point to read about custom actions is [here](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/IHelpCustomActions.htm).

Comment: Your links are dead, fyi.

Comment: @Moussamoa thank you, I updated them. The resources were moved

Comment: The documentation talks about check box, but I can't find any checkbox related to that.